# How to get coordinates with a mouse click in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, mouse, x86-16

So i need to make a rectangle using a click of a mouse(coordinates of the top-left corner).I just don't know how to use multiple functions in the same register.I need help getting the coordinates from a mouse click.
Code(the middle part is the one with coordinates,but doesn't work):

```
model small
.stack 100
.data
 y1 dw 50
 x dw 130
 y2 dw 100
 l db 100; lenght
 k db 50;width

.code
 mov ax,@data
 mov ds,ax
 mov ah,0h
 mov al,13h; graphic mode 13h (320 x 200)
 int 10h
```

```
 MOV AX,01
 int 33h
 MOV AX, 05H
 int 33h
 pop ax
 mov x,cx
 cmp ax,1
 jnz ciclu1
```

```
 mov dx,y1
 mov cx,x
 mov al,5; color
 mov bl,l; lenght
 mov ah,0ch
 mov bh,0
ciclu1: int 10h ; light pixel on(cx,dx)
 push dx
 mov dx,y2
 int 10h
 pop dx
 inc cx
 dec bl
 jnz ciclu1
 mov bl,k; width
ciclu2: int 10h ; light pixel (cx,dx)
 push cx
 mov cx,x
 int 10h
 pop cx
 inc dx
 dec bl
 jnz ciclu2
 mov ah,01h
 int 21h
 mov ah,0h
 mov al,3h;
 int 10h
 mov ah,4ch
 int 21h
end
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate architecture etc., this makes your question visible to the right people. Can you elaborate on what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: What is the reason to `pop ax` immediately after the `int 33,5`?  That's going to wipe out the button flags.

Comment: my mouse doesn't show up if i don't pop ax.